# How to register LLC in the US from India?

Tags: united-states, india, limited-liability-company

I am living in India. I have an online business with many clients in the US, and I want to register it as an LLC in the US.

Which state is the best to register in?

What is the process for me to register my company in the US?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not register LLC in India?

Comment: some clients requirements.

Comment: Usually these clients try to circumvent tax laws, and you would probably get in trouble with them. Check this out and be careful.

Answer (score -1):

Wyoming is a good state for this. It is inexpensive and annual compliance is minimal.

Although Delaware has the best advertising campaign, so people know about it, the reality is  that there are over 50 states/jurisdictions in the United States with their own competitive incorporation laws to attract investment (as well as their own legislative bodies that change those laws), so you just have to read the laws to find a state that is favorable for you. What I mean is that whatever Delaware does to get in the news about its easy business laws, has been mimicked and done even better by other states by this point in time. And regarding Delaware's Chancery Court, all other states in the union can also lean on Delaware case law, so this perk is not unique to Delaware.

Wyoming is cheaper than Delaware for nominal presence in the United States, requires less information then Delaware, and is also tax free.

A "registered agent" can get you set up and you can find one to help you with the address dilemma. This should only cost $99 - $200 over the state fees. An LLC does not need to have an address in the United States, but many registered agents will let you use their address, just ask.

Many kinds of businesses still require a bank account for domestic and global trade. Many don't require any financial intermediary any more to receive payments. But if you do need this, then opening a bank account in the United States will be more difficult. Again, the registered agent or lawyer can get a Tax Identification Number for you from the IRS, and this will be necessary to open a US bank account.

But it is more likely that you will need an employee or nominee director in the United States to go in person to a bank and open an account. This person needs to be mentioned in the Operating Agreement or other official form on the incorporation documents. They will simply walk into a bank with your articles of incorporation and operating agreement showing that they are authorized to act on behalf of the entity and open a bank account.

They then resign, and this is a private document between the LLC and the employee. But you will be able to receive and accept payments and access the global financial system now.

A lot of multinational entities set up subsidiaries in a number of countries this way.